# ETL - SFTP servers to hive tables

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, etl

I want to set up a data pipeline which processes files(of different format) from SFTP server and lands them into hive(backed by S3). Each file type i.e. e.g. CSV, TEXT etc will have a spec which will be used to interpret fields in the file. We'll need to map each of this field to a field in destination hive schema. Following are few nice to have features.

1. The path from SFTP server to the hive is split into intermediate stages for ease of debugging and modularity.
2. Each file is processed only once. Re-processing of the file should overwrite previous records from that file that are processed.

Here's what I am thinking:

Stage 1 would read files from SFTP and dump it into S3. This stage would run at regular intervals and is very lightweight. It would have retries and stuff.

Stage 2 would read those files from S3 and run it through series of validation, transformation and convert it into a CSV file. Basically files from each processor are converted into CSV format, no matter what the original format was. This new file is stored in a different location.

Stage 3 takes this CSV file and creates a hive table on top of it.

Are there any open source projects I could use for my use case? Is there any other approach you guys recommend?

Answer (score 1):

1. I'd use hive with the source an sftp:// path and dest as s3a://.
2. But I wouldn't use .csv as a persistence format. because it sucks. ORC or Parquet for performance queries, or Avro for interchange.